# Asterisk AMI IVR. NodeJS

Tags: node.js, asterisk, sip, voip

Возможно ли на чистом AMI, без прописывания каких-то дополнительных правил в extension, создать такую схему:

Сервер берет из списка первый номер и звонит ему. Когда человек поднимает трубку, ему проигрывается аудиозапись. Далее ожидаем от него положительный ответ и запускаем следующее аудио.

Позвонить клиенту я смог, проигрывание аудио тоже. Но дело в том, что после проигрывания аудио сразу идет сброс звонка. Что нужно сделать для того, чтобы после проигрывания аудио, запускать следующие события (запись разговора, воспроизведение аудио).

extension.conf:

```
[general]
static=yes
writeprotect=no
priorityjumping=no
autofallthrough=yes
clearglobalvars=no

[call]
exten => _XXXX,1,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN})
```

nodejs скрипт:

```html
const ami = new require('asterisk-manager')('5038','localhost','admin','123456', true);
ami.keepConnected();



ami.on("bridgeenter", function(evt) {
  ami.action({
            action: 'originate',
            channel: evt.channel,
            application: 'Playback',
            data: '/home/dev/records/1666610222.539'
          }, function(err, res) {
            console.log(err, res);
          })
})


ami.action({
    'action':'originate',
    'channel':'Local/1002@call',
    'application': 'Playback',
    'data': '/home/dev/records/1666610222.539',
    'callerid': 'serv',
  }, function(err, res) {
    if(res.response == "Success") {
      ami.action({
        'action':'originate',
        'channel':'Local/1002@call',
        'application': 'Playback',
        'data': '/home/dev/records/1666610222.539',
        'callerid': 'serv',
      })
    }
  });
```

Comment: я так понимаю код проигрывания аудио идет в if(res.response == "Success") {....} ??

Answer (score 0):

```
const ami = new require('asterisk-manager')('5038','localhost','admin','123456', true);
ami.keepConnected();



ami.on("bridgeenter", function(evt) {
  ami.action({
            action: 'originate',
            channel: evt.channel,
            application: 'Playback',
            data: '/home/dev/records/1666610222.539'
          }, function(err, res) {
            console.log(err, res);
          })
})


ami.action({
    'action':'originate',
    'channel':'Local/1002@call',
    'application': 'Playback',
    'data': '/home/dev/records/1666610222.539',
    'callerid': 'serv',
  }, function(err, res) {
    if(res.response == "Success") {
      //правильно ли я понимаю что проигрывание аудио идет здесь?
      ami.action({
        'action':'originate',
        'channel':'Local/1002@call',
        'application': 'Playback',
        'data': '/home/dev/records/1666610222.539',
        'callerid': 'serv',
      })

      //тогда следуйщие действия должны быть тут
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    function sleep(ms) {
      return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    }


   const ami = new require('asterisk-manager')('5038','localhost','admin','123456', true);
ami.keepConnected();



ami.on("bridgeenter", function(evt) {
  ami.action({
            action: 'originate',
            channel: evt.channel,
            application: 'Playback',
            data: '/home/dev/records/1666610222.539'
          }, function(err, res) {
            console.log(err, res);
          })
})


ami.action({
    'action':'originate',
    'channel':'Local/1002@call',
    'application': 'Playback',
    'data': '/home/dev/records/1666610222.539',
    'callerid': 'serv',
  }, async function(err, res) {
    if(res.response == "Success") {
      //правильно ли я понимаю что проигрывание аудио идет здесь?
      ami.action({
        'action':'originate',
        'channel':'Local/1002@call',
        'application': 'Playback',
        'data': '/home/dev/records/1666610222.539',
        'callerid': 'serv',
      })

      //попробуйте так:
      await sleep(3000);

      ami.action({
        'action':'originate',
        'channel':'Local/1002@call',
        'application': 'Playback',
        'data': '/home/dev/records/1666610222.539',
        'callerid': 'serv',
      });
    }
  });
```

по идее вы подождете 3 секунды и снова включите ту же запись на воспроизведение. Поменять вы ее можете на любую другую другую.